# system of ordinary differential equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

Suppose we have this Hamiltonian:

```
n = 10;
H = ones(n,n);
```

The density matrix is:

```
Ro = sym('r',[n,n]);%Density matrix
```

The equation of motion is:

```
 H*Ro-Ro*H
```

The above equation of motion is the right hand side of the equation, the left hand side is the time derivative of density matrix.

How can I solve the equation of motion in Matlab without the symbolic math toolbox? I need to change the value of n. It can be up to 100.

Comment: By "solve" do you mean integrate the system for a finite time `T` from some initial conditions `x0`?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. The initial condition could be a matrix which only its (1,1) element is non zero and equal to one.

Answer (score 0):

In your dynamics function, reshape between vectors and matrices in order to use MATLAB's [standard `ode` functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html#bu3n5rf-1), which (to my knowledge) require vector inputs. Note, the symbolic toolbox isn't used anywhere in this solution. `R` can be any size `n-by-n`, within the constraints of your machine's memory.

```
function dR = dynfun(R,H)
                                %// R    = n^2-by-1 vector
                                %// H    = n-by-n matrix
    n  = sqrt(length(R));       
    R  = reshape(R,[n,n]);      %// reshape R to n-by-n matrix
    dR = H*R-R*H;              
    dR = dR(:);                 %// reshape dR to n^2-by-1 vector


end
```

Call the ODE solver:

```
[tout,Rout] = ode45(@(t,R) dynfun(R,H), [0,T], R0(:));
```

where `T` is final time, `R0` is `n-by-n` initial condition, `tout` are the output time steps, and `Rout` is the solution trajectory. Note due to the reshaping, `Rout` will be `k-by-n^2`, where `k` is the number of time steps. You'll need to reshape each row of `Rout` if you want to have the actual matrices over time.